# Equivelant way of performing Ruby's array.pack in Python

Tags: python, ruby, equivalent

I have a Ruby function that looks like this:

```
def domain_request
  pkt = "0300000c02f0800400010001"
  return [pkt].pack("H*")
end
```

Basically what I would like to do is perform the same thing in Python (if you could also provide reference to the pack formats it would be greatly appreciated) I've attempted to do so from a `bytearray` however, I'm at a loss at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I have no idea what ruby's pack does, but I wonder if it's similar to Python's [struct.pack](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).

Comment: @Kevin that's what I originally thought! But the problem with that is that ruby's pack can take multiple arguments (in an array) and pack them at the same time, while python's struct doesn't. I guess I could use a for loop on it to see if it would do anything, but so far I have been unsuccessful

Comment: There's times I think I'm getting somewhere coding - then I look at the source docs for ruby's pack method and curl up in a ball.

Comment: @Mark 99.99% of the time I have no idea what I'm doing, so don't feel to bad. Just yesterday I blue screened my VM trying to connect to it with a socket request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like what you want

```
from binascii import unhexlify

str = "0300000c02f0800400010001"
unhexlify(str)
```

Although the output of ruby appears slightly different, comparing these in both ruby and python both are true, this code works in both python and ruby:

```
s1 = "\x03\x00\x00\x0c\x02\xf0\x80\x04\x00\x01\x00\x01"
s2 = "\x03\x00\x00\f\x02\xF0\x80\x04\x00\x01\x00\x01"

s1 == s2 #=> true or True in python
```

Comment: I don't want to decode it, I want to pack it into bytes in the same format. However given the comment I just received, it seems Python doesn't have something, so binascii might be my best bet, or I could use system commands I guess

Comment: test the result. it returns the same value as your ruby method

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: you are a genius

Comment: well, maybe not, for some reason, the ruby version actually returns a slightly different value... py version looks more correct to me

Comment: Looking at it through wireshark they look extremely similar, so it might work successfully